# Entity Query for ISystems and SystemBase in Unity ECS 1.0

Tags: unity-dots

I have a tile based building game in Unity ECS 1.0, where I add particular `IComponentData` to several systems. From a `PlayerInput` which is a `MonoBehavior` (because `PlayerInput` and `InputActions` are not translated to ECS), I tried to query all systems having that `IComponentData`. But I found that regular `EntityQueries` do not match for `Entity` representation of systems, so I had to use `EntityManager.UniversalQueryWithSystems`, which returns the `Entity` representation of all systems. There I do a for loop and check all systems for that particular component.
Does anybody know if there is a more performant way to check for these components on systems?
I already tried to return `EntityManager.UniversalQueryWithSystems.ToComponentDataArray<MyComponent>()`, but then it's complaining, that the query have not been initialized using this component (which of course I may not change, as it's not my own query).

Comment: Why not just going `SystemName.Singleton` path? I.e. singleton for every system that needs data hosting. Easy access, straight forward structure, no unnecessary complexities.

Comment: Because I want to write back the "progress" of the according systems. This means that I sometimes only partially progress the data of the systems in one frame. But anyway I was wondering if there is a way to get the `IComponentData` without a relation to the system itself (because the way you propose, is to get the system as a singleton and then read it's components, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it. You can pass options to an `EntityQueryBuilder` or a call to `SystemAPI.Query<>(..)` with the method `.WithOptions(..)` then just pass `EntityQueryOptions.IncludeSystems`.

So a complete call could look like this:

```
public static NativeArray<Entity> GetSystemsManaged<T>() where T : struct, IComponentData
{
    if (World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld == null
        || !World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.IsCreated
        || World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.EntityManager == null)
    {
        return new NativeArray<Entity>(0, Allocator.Temp);
    }
    EntityManager entityManager = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.EntityManager;
    EntityQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new EntityQueryBuilder(Allocator.Temp)
        .WithAll<T>()
        .WithOptions(EntityQueryOptions.IncludeSystems);
    EntityQuery entityQuery = entityManager.CreateEntityQuery(queryBuilder);
    NativeArray<Entity> result = entityQuery.ToEntityArray(Allocator.Temp);
    queryBuilder.Dispose();
    entityQuery.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```